# Canvas: Getting blank image after pressing Button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I m trying to take image from screen of live video by using canvas method. But when i press **capture** and press **View URI** button i get only blank image. I also saw this post: [Javascript Canvas Blank Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445758/javascript-canvas-blank-image)  but made no help.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="video" width="20%" height="419" src="http://videoplayer.vodobox.com/vodobox_player.php?vid=http://109.123.70.72:1935/live/ptvsports/samitv.m3u8&img=&play=?" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <br/>
            <button onClick="capture()" style="width: 64px;border: solid
2px #ccc;">Capture</button><br/>


<div id="container" style="border:none">

     <canvas id="imageView" style="display:none; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;border:none" width="300" height="200">

     </canvas>

</div>

<div id="imgs" style="border:solid">

</div>

<script>


       function getURIformcanvas() {
           var ImageURItoShow = "";
           var canvasFromVideo = document.getElementById("imageView");
           if (canvasFromVideo.getContext) {
               var ctx = canvasFromVideo.getContext("2d"); // Get the context for the canvas.canvasFromVideo.
               var ImageURItoShow = canvasFromVideo.toDataURL("image/png");

           }


           var imgs = document.getElementById("imgs");

           imgs.appendChild(Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvasFromVideo, 300, 200, 'png'));


       }

       var videoId = 'video';


       function capture() {
           var video = document.getElementById("video");


           var canvasDraw = document.getElementById('imageView');
           var w = canvasDraw.width;
           var h = canvasDraw.height;
           var ctxDraw = canvasDraw.getContext('2d');

           ctxDraw.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

           ctxDraw.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
           ctxDraw.save();


           getURIformcanvas();   


       }
   </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

output:
[image]

Comment: You are trying to capture the content of an iframe into a canvas? That cannot be done (this way). `ctx.drawImage` will draw an image (surprise!), i.e. something in the lines of jpg, png, svg etc.

Comment: You probably have an error stating that argument one of drawimage is not of type image, video,canvas... You are passing an iframe,  not a video element .

Comment: then what shd i do bcz i want to capture frame from iframe video and display below.

Comment: is there anyway to do so? i am trying my best.

Comment: Here's example code from a previous Stackoverflow [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917800/screenshot-from-video-at-different-time/33925844#33925844).

Comment: thnx but it is not working with uframe. any idea? why the hell is not helping .?

Comment: even my code supports <video>....</video> but not supporting <iframe> i dont know why this is happening